# Ruby on Rails Max Length in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have my index.html.erb for my /articles
and I have a list of all my articles, with its description.
So then in the show.html.erb for the articles, the description is 500 characters of length. 
How do I display in the index.html.erb only 250 characters, then a read more link?

Comment: This is not a rails question, and worst yet as a ruby question. It is an HTML/CSS one. And it is better you come with what you have tried up to now - right now all I see is a short question from someone that didn't even googled about this.

Comment: First of all, this is a ruby on rails question, hence the TAGS. It could also be an HTML/CSS one, but thats not what I was asking was it!
And as you can see from the answer below, it works perfectly with RoR!
So check your facts before being all rude

Oh and "even googled about this" makes no sense.

Comment: Removed the -1 and edited your question. Yet, I don't believe you couldn't figure this with a simple google serach. Next time, if you have no way to show a previous tentatives, at least show your queries on google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) method.

So let's say that your description is `description`.

In your view, you would have something like this followed by a `link_to` tag to your read more page.

`<%= truncate(description, length: 250) %>`

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple like this,

<%= article.description[0,250] % >

it will print only first 250 character of description.